# Adding Custom Option For Multiple Products at once . Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, custom-options, script

I have an category of *Watches* and in this category there is more then *2500* Products now I want to add **Custom Option** on each Product for that I was following [This](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-custom-option-programmatically-in-magento-2/#:%7E:text=Magento%202%2C%20Product%20with%20custom,Admin%20side%20in%20product%20Section) link so when I write script for it. it was working fine on *one* product but when I **Run** the **script** for the whole category then **Custom Option** was not added in any single product. While when I *Break* the **loop** after only one *Iteration* then again works for only *one* product my script is

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 
$params = $_SERVER;
 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 
$category = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load(66);
$optionFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option');
$productagain = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); 
$productrepo = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
echo $category->getName();
$catproducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$inputbox =array(
                "sort_order"    => 1,
                "title"         => "Weist Size (in cm)",
                "price_type"    => "fixed",
                "price"         => "",
                "type"          => "field",
                "is_require"    => 1
            );

foreach ($catproducts as $_product){
    echo $_product->getSku()."<br>";
    echo $_product->getId()."<br>";
    echo $_product->getStoreId()."<br>";
        $option = $optionFactory
                    ->setProductId($_product->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
                    ->addData($inputbox);
            $option->save();
            echo"Working";
            $_product->addOption($option);
            $productrepo->save($_product);
            //break;
}
?>
```

**In Simple Words When I iterate through products and try to add custom options it fails but the same code works for single product**. Thanks

Comment: you used $again->getId() and $again->getStoreId() inside the loop, it seems should be $_product->getId() and $_product->getStoreId() instead

Comment: sorry it was coding mistake I set it but in this scenario same thing happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use  Option factory

```
$obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory')->create()
 ->setProductId($_product->getId())
 ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
 ->addData($inputbox);
$option->save();
```

Hope it would help :)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Hope it will work. What i did is just moved **$productrepo** line inside loop.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 
$params = $_SERVER;
 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 
$category = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load(66);
$optionFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option');
$productagain = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); 
echo $category->getName();
$catproducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$inputbox =array(
                "sort_order"    => 1,
                "title"         => "Weist Size (in cm)",
                "price_type"    => "fixed",
                "price"         => "",
                "type"          => "field",
                "is_require"    => 1
            );

foreach ($catproducts as $_product){
    $productrepo = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    echo $_product->getSku()."<br>";
    echo $_product->getId()."<br>";
    echo $_product->getStoreId()."<br>";
        $option = $optionFactory
                    ->setProductId($_product->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
                    ->addData($inputbox);
            $option->save();
            echo"Working";
            $_product->addOption($option);
            $productrepo->save($_product);
            //break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your response but the same scenario is happening it works only for one product... for full loop it doesnt work I'm not getting that why this is not working